# HTML5 input type range is not setting to initial value of model AngularJS

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am using HTML5 input type of range for slider functionality and binding it to my model.

By default my model will have a value in it, but slider is taking only min and max not value. When I go back from that screen and coming back, slider goes to left end but value remains what I gave last time only.

```js
$scope.maxAmt = $rootScope.maxAmt;
$scope.minAmt = $rootScope.minAmt;
$scope.loanAmt = 5000;
```

```html
<input type="range" min="{{minAmt}}" max="{{maxAmt}}"
                     value="{{loanAmt}}" step="500"
                     ng-model="loanAmt"
                     >
<output name="loanAmt">{{loanAmt}}</output>
```

[image: click here]

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6726